# Web API post data: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get Web API working with POST and I have the following in my Controller:

```
public class mainGridController : ApiController
    {

        public class formData
        {
            public string module { get; set; }
            public string group { get; set; }
            public string staff { get; set; }
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] formData data)
        {
            string string_group = "";
            string string_staff = "";

            if (data.group != null)
            {
```

But I seem to be getting "object reference is not set to an instance of an object" for data.group in my "if" statement.

Here is my route info:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{data}",
            defaults: new { module = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional, data = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I am trying to post using jQuery.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var url = "api/mainGrid";
var source = {
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    id: "SEQUENCE",
    root: 'rowsinfo',
    cache: false,
    columns: [],
    datafields: [],
    beforeprocessing: function (data) {
        var columnsdata = new Array();
        var datafieldsdata = new Array();
        for (k in data.columnsinfo) {
            var col = {};
            col.text = data.columnsinfo[k]["DISPLAYNAME"];
            col.datafield = data.columnsinfo[k]["DISPLAYNAME"];
            var datafields = {};
            datafields.name = data.columnsinfo[k]["DISPLAYNAME"];
            columnsdata.push(col);
            datafieldsdata.push(datafields);
            source.columns = columnsdata;
            source.datafields = datafieldsdata;
        }
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({ columns: source.columns });
    },
    data: {
        group: JSON.stringify(checkedGroups),
        staff: JSON.stringify(checkedStaff),
        module: selectedModuleSEQ
    }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your jQuery code, that's quite important. FYI when using C# it's [recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) that you use Pascal casing for class names.

Comment: Thanks James, just posted... I will change the class name thank you!

Comment: checkedGroups and checkedStaff are both javascript arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have specified the `dataType` parameter as `json` but you are passing a JS *object* - which of course isn't JSON.

You need to convert your `data` object to actual JSON for this to work

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    group: JSON.stringify(checkedGroups),
    staff: JSON.stringify(checkedStaff),
    module: JSON.stringify(selectedModuleSEQ)
}),
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you James. FYI I also had to change [FromBody] to [FromUri]

Comment: @realtek so is the JSON being posted in the URL? You could try `data: { json: JSON.stringify({ ... }) }` instead.

Comment: Hi James, sorry I thought it was but the variable was being set in my If statement.... it still doesn't seem to be coming through?

Comment: @realtek so you are using the approach in my answer and using `[FromBody]` and it's still `null`? The only thing I can see is the properties i.e. `group`/`staff`/`module` are `string` on the server but they appear to be models at the client. Either call `JSON.stringify` on each individual property data client-side as well or update your server model to expect a model for each rather than a string.

Comment: Thats correct I have tried your approach but its still null?

Comment: @realtek this is including calling `JSON.stringify` on the individual property data as well? See the updated answer.

Comment: I have tried data: {
        json: {
            group: JSON.stringify(checkedGroups),
            staff: JSON.stringify(checkedStaff),
            module: JSON.stringify(selectedModuleSEQ)
        } is that what you mean? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47424/discussion-between-realtek-and-james)